# Way to run aws cli across multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I am trying to find out all EC2 instances in 10 different accounts which are running non-amazon AMI images. Following CLI command gives me the list of all AMI's:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ImageId]' | sort | uniq -c
```

I think I can modify this further to get all non-amazon AMI's but is there a way to run this across 10 different accounts in one call?

Comment: This is probably going to be simpler in Python, using boto3.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to run this across 10 different accounts in one call?

No, that's not possible. You need to write a loop that iterates over each account, calling `ec2 describe-instances` once for each account.

Comment: Is the cli command I wrote good? Or can this be written better to find non-amazon ami's?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could filter by AMI owner in an `ec2 describe-instances` call, since that information is not included in the response.

Comment: I dont need to filter by owner. I just need to know if AMI is amazon image or custom. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The owner is how you check that. You would check if Amazon is the owner.

Comment: This does not have owner: aws ec2 describe-instances. I only get owner if i search by linux or windows. Am i missing something?

Comment: As I said, you need to look at the AMI Owner to determine if it is an AWS image or a customer created AMIs, but you don't get that information in a describe-instances call, so you are going to have to make multiple calls to determine this, and then multiply that by the number of accounts you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that can find instances using AMIs where the Owner is not `amazon`:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

instances = ec2_client.describe_instances()

# Get a set of AMIs used on all the instances
images = set(i['ImageId'] for r in instances['Reservations'] for i in r['Instances'])

# Find which of these are owned by Amazon
amis = ec2_client.describe_images(ImageIds=list(images), Owners=['amazon'])
amazon_amis = [i['ImageId'] for i in amis['Images']]

# Which instances are not using Amazon images?
non_amazon_instances = [(i['InstanceId'], i['ImageId']) for r in instances['Reservations'] for i in r['Instances'] if i['ImageId'] not in amazon_amis]

for i in non_amazon_instances:
    print(f"{i[0]} uses {i[1]}")
```

A few things to note:

- Deprecated AMIs might not have accessible information, so might be marked a non-Amazon.
- This script, as written, only works on one region. You could change it to loop through regions.
- This script, as written, only works on one account. You would need a way to loop through credentials for other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS config

1. Create an agregator in root or delegated account(wait for the agregator to load)
2. Create query

```
SELECT
  accountId,
  resourceId,
  configuration.keyName,
  availabilityZone
WHERE
  resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  AND configuration.state.name = 'running'
```

more details
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/org-aggregator-delegated-admin/

Answer (score 0):

Old Post, I know, but just ran into this...   I use Steampipe (steampipe.org) for these types of queries (with their AWS plugin).  We have a dozen or so AWS accounts, so this definitely helps.  I use Steampipe daily for my work queries, including other plugins like CVS (awesome plugin) and Crowdstrike.

Steampipe uses SQL and maps these to API calls.  You don't need a vast knowledge of SQL to use this, and once your brain gets used to this, it is pretty nice.

````
SELECT
  account_id, 
  instance_id,
  tags->>'Name' AS name_tag
FROM
  aws_account_prod.aws_ec2_instance;
WHERE
  instance_state = 'running'```
````