# How to iterate through multiple AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Consider an AWS organization with 50+ accounts. Each account has a role created that allows read-only access to the EC2 service - named "EC2ReadAccess" - and a trust relationship with the master(/management) account. A single IAM user in the master account has a policy applied to allow it to assume the role in every single account.

I would like to be able to iterate through all the accounts in order to retrieve all the EC2 instances, using the unique IAM user. I know that running a CLI command against all the accounts at once is [out of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359926/way-to-run-aws-cli-across-multiple-accounts). Leaving aside cycling through the regions in each account, which has been [discussed extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086712/how-to-see-all-running-amazon-ec2-instances-across-all-regions), **is there an elegant solution for doing this?**

One hack that comes to mind is to programmatically build the `credentials` file so that it contains a profile for each account. Each profile, in turn, will be "linked" to the profile of the IAM user (as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)), and have the account id within the role updated for each entry. An example below:

```ini
[user1]
aws_access_key_id=<key_id>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>

[marketing]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/EC2ReadAccess
source_profile = user1
[dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::234567890123:role/EC2ReadAccess
source_profile = user1
...
[prod]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::345678901234:role/EC2ReadAccess
source_profile = user1
```

Running the CLI command - in this case `aws ec2 describe-instances` - can be accompanied by the `--profile` parameter in order to cycle through all the profiles present in the `credentials` file. The region can be cycled through within another loop. So a list of commands to be issued, generated programmatically beforehand, could look something like:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile marketing --region us-east-1
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile marketing --region us-east-2
...
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile marketing --region sa-east-1
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile dev --region us-east-1
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile dev --region us-east-2
...
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile dev --region sa-east-1
...
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile prod --region us-east-1
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile prod --region us-east-2
...
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile prod --region sa-east-1
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You really only need a list of account IDs, because your role arn name is consistent. You will need to manually `assume-role` if you are not using `--profile` in this way, though.

Comment: @jordanm: not sure I follow. Do you mean that as input to my "hack", the list of account ids would do? Or that I can somehow specify the account id directly as a parameter to the aws ec2 command?

Comment: Frankly, I'd do it through an SDK (eg Python) rather than using the CLI. Much easier to do loops and handle the response that comes back. I'd use a list of Account IDs rather than profiles. But, it would be the same general "loop within a loop".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: 100% agreed, as eventually, I'll be using the AWS SDK for .NET. From my limited testing so far though, the AmazonEC2Client() constructor relies on the profiles specified within the credential file; there are multiple overloads where credentials can be passed through, and need to look into those as well. I'm just using the CLI to wrap my mind around the concepts and to cross-check the results easily.

Comment: I would not use multiple profiles. Simply change the `RoleArn` value passed to the `AssumeRole()` command. If each sub-account has the same role name, it would just be a matter of inserting the Account ID into the `RoleArn`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the CLI to do this. If you're able to "programmatically build the credentials file", then you should be able to write a program that does the following for every child account:

1. Assumes the administrator role for that account.
2. Invokes the DescribeInstances API call.
3. Do whatever you want with the information

You don't indicate what programming language(s) you're familiar with, but here's some Python that I use to create an SDK client with the standard "OrganizationalAccountAccessRole" in a child account:

```py
def create_boto_resource(account, region, resource_type):
    creds = assumeRole(account)
    return boto3.resource(resource_type,
                          region_name=region,
                          aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
                          aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
                          aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken'])



def assumeRole(account, role_name='OrganizationAccountAccessRole', duration=900):
    stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
    request = {}
    request['RoleArn']         = f"arn:aws:iam::{account}:role/{role_name}"
    request['RoleSessionName'] = 'DESCRIPTIVE_TEXT_HERE'
    request['DurationSeconds'] = duration
    return stsClient.assume_role(**request)['Credentials']
```

This code actually creates a Boto resource object, which is a simplified API that's supported for EC2 and a few other services. [Here's](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.instances) and example of using the resource API to create an instance iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to attack this kind of problem might be via [Systems Manager Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-inventory.html) and [Querying inventory data from multiple Regions and accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-inventory-query.html).

Comment: The main issue I'm seeing - aside from the cost for Amazon Athena and AWS Glue - is the fact that the SSM agent has to be deployed on every EC2 instance to be monitored

Comment: Yes, though it's [installed by default](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/install-ssm-agent-ec2-linux/) in many cases.